# Concatenate string and variable to get variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to pass a string into a function, concatenate it with a common suffix, and use that new string as an existing variable. For example,

```
var firstInfo = "The first string says this.";

var secondInfo = "The second says that.";

updateInfo(arg)
{
    console.log(arg + "Info");
}

updateInfo("first");
/* Should print "The first string says this.", but instead does nothing. */
```

What am I doing wrong? This is plain javascript, but I am open to other libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript function eval() , here's the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
var firstInfo = "The first string says this.";

var secondInfo = "The second says that.";

function updateInfo(arg)
{
    console.log( eval(arg + "Info") );
}

updateInfo("first");
```

Comment: Before when I was reading about eval(), it had such a bad rap that I did't want to try it. But you have proved it to be the correct solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `window[arg + "Info"]` to get a value of global variable:

```
console.log(window[arg + "Info"]);
```

Here is a full [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hw3ojbt/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
updateInfo(arg)
{
    firstInfo = arg + "Info";
    console.log(firstInfo );
}

    updateInfo(firstInfo );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "firstInfo" variable is defined in the global scope, and is hence attached to window object.
If you console it in the function scope without the window reference it will be invoked with the local scope.

Try this I have used the window object.

```
var firstInfo = "The first string says this.";

var secondInfo = "The second says that.";

function updateInfo(arg)
{
    console.log(window[arg + "Info"]);
}

updateInfo("first");
```